# Filter data in React Native Section List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm using React Native's SectionList. The data to the SectionList looks something like this

```
data: [
    {
      title: "Asia",
      data: ["Taj Mahal", "Great Wall of China", "Petra"]
    },
    {
      title: "South America",
      data: ["Machu Picchu", "Christ the Redeemer", "Chichen Itza"]
    },
    {
      title: "Europe",
      data: ["Roman Colosseum"]
    }
  ]
```

I have a Text Input using which I try to filter out contents in the SectionList. I tried using `Array.filter()` and it doesn't seem to work. It returns me the entire data without any filtering. So, I tried `Array.some()`. Now all the data items in the section are being filtered when even one item matches it. This behavior is expected out of `Array.some()`. But I'm confused why `Array.filter()` is not working in my case.

My SectionList looks something like this,

```
<SectionList 
      sections={this.state.data.filter(sectionData => {
        sectionData = sectionData.data;
        return sectionData.filter(data => {
          return data.includes(this.state.searchTerm);
        })
      })}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => ( <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{title}</Text> )}
      renderItem={({ item }) => ( <Text style={styles.listItem}>{item}</Text>)}
      keyExtractor={item => item}
    />
```

Here's the link for [Expo Playground](https://snack.expo.io/BJa1yRgQm) if you wish to play with it online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`filter` will create a new array with all the entries that returned a truthy value. Your second filter will always return at least an empty array, which is truthy, and thus you get all your sections in the final result.

You could try a combination of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and `filter` instead:

```
this.state.data.reduce((result, sectionData) => {
  const { title, data } = sectionData;
  const filteredData = data.filter(
    element => element.includes(this.state.searchTerm)
  );

  if (filteredData.length !== 0) {
    result.push({
      title,
      data: filteredData
    });
  }

  return result;
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks much. Using reducers actually solved my problem.