# Case Insensitive Filter of React Native SectionList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to do a "case insensitive" filter on a SectionList in react native. The data looks something like this:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"]
  }
];
```

I understand that I have to use "reduce" and "filter" together to filter through the complete object data to pass to SectionList, thanks to [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245478/13338195) from [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle).

BUT...
I want to ensure **filtering is case insensitive**? Essentially a filter for the search text "RI" should give me an output:

```
Main dishes
  Risotto

Sides
  French Fries
  Onion Rings
  Fried Shrimps
```

*Would appreciate your help!*

Comment: It is case sensitive. 
If you want to make it case insensitive then convert your iterating element to all uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to convert the search query and all elements you're iterating over to the common form, e.g. make them all lowercase.

```js
const searchQuery = "RI"

const result = DATA.reduce((accumulator, currentObj) => {
  let output = {}
  const transformedSearchQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase()
  const currentTitle = currentObj.title
  const currentData = currentObj.data

  const filteredData = currentData.filter(item => {
    const transformedItem = item.toLowerCase()
    return transformedItem.includes(transformedSearchQuery)
  })

  if (filteredData.length) {
    output.title = currentTitle
    output.data = filteredData
  }

  if (Object.entries(output).length) {
    return [...accumulator, output]
  } else {
    return accumulator
  }
}, [])
```

Output:

```
console.log(result)

[
  { title: 'Main dishes', data: [ 'Risotto' ] },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: [ 'French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps' ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @morteify. Really helps! I gather then that there aren't any methods (like toLowerCase for strings) which can operate on the full array object.